# php and bootstrap login

Tags: php, mysql, twitter-bootstrap

i am working on a login form, i try this php code for login.php:

```
    <?php
       session_start();
            // Connect to MySQL
  $mysqli = new mysqli( 'localhost', 'cshrnaf_user2', '=cXlIBsdMkdr', 'cshrnaf_mis_db' );
       if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
          // username and password sent from form 

          $myusername = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['Username']);
          $mypassword = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['Password']); 

          $sql = "SELECT id FROM user WHERE email = '$myusername' and password= '$mypassword'";
          $result = mysqli_query($db,$sql);
          $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
          $active = $row['active'];

          $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

          // If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row

          if($count == 1) {
             session_register("myusername");
             $_SESSION['login_user'] = $myusername;

             header("location: index.php");
          }else {
             $error = "Your Login Name or Password is invalid";
          }
       }
    ?>
```

and here is my bootstrap code:

```
</head>
<body class="gray-bg">
    <div class="middle-box text-center loginscreen animated fadeInDown">
        <div>
            <h3>Welcome</h3>
            <p>Login to your account.</p>
            <form method="post" class="m-t" role="form">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" name=Username required="">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" name=Password required="">
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary block full-width m-b">Login</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    </body>
</head>
```

but it gives me error at line 7,8,11,12 and 15. is there anything wrong with my php code or html one?

Comment: Post your errors in your question???

Comment: In order to prevent **SQL Injection** use Prepared Statements : http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Comment: You're storing passwords in plain text? You need to stop right now.

Answer (score 2):

which line are 7,8,11, 12 and 15 actually, line number aren't showing here. Beside, you should post the error messages so them someone can actually help you out.

I think you are using an undefined variable `$db` in your code. That's the only problem I am seeing here. If `$db` is an instance of your `DB` connection that that connection code should be here, but its absent here.

Updated part hare:

The problem is with `$result` variable. You have stored the `mysqli_query`  result on the `$result` variable. But when the `mysqli_query` fails then the result is `false`. As a result,the error are being shown as you have told in comment. here is you can take a look: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

You should update your code to this:

```
<?php
       session_start();
            // Connect to MySQL
  $mysqli = new mysqli( 'localhost', 'cshrnaf_user2', '=cXlIBsdMkdr', 'cshrnaf_mis_db' );
       if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
          // username and password sent from form 

          $myusername = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['Username']);
          $mypassword = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['Password']); 

          $sql = "SELECT id FROM user WHERE email = '$myusername' and password= '$mypassword'";
          if($result = mysqli_query($db,$sql)){
              $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
              $active = $row['active'];

              $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

              // If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row

              if($count == 1) {
                 session_register("myusername");
                 $_SESSION['login_user'] = $myusername;

                 header("location: index.php");
              }else {
                 $error = "Your Login Name or Password is invalid";
              }
           }else{
               echo "<br>Query fails";
           }
       }
    ?>
```

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer - you can't know that `$db` is not assigned somewhere else - therefore you should really ask

Comment: I have count the line numbers by they, in every line where the variable `$db` used is producing an error as he mentioned.

Comment: @Al-ImranAhmed i re-edit my code could you please take a look at php one? Thanks : )

Comment: hmm, you have created a variable named as `$mysqli` to hold the instance of db but you are using `$db` variable without declaring. You can try by replacing `$mysqli` with `$db`.

Comment: @Al-imranAhmed i replace it now it gives me error at line 14 and 17 which is       $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);  AND       $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

Comment: @al-ImranAhmed  Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in /home/cssh/public_html/MIS_cssh/login.php on line 13

Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in /home/cssh/public_html/MIS_cssh/login.php on line 16

Comment: @Al-ImranAhmed i tried the new code you give me friend, but still i got errors at line 8,9 and 12 which are: 
Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in /home/cshrnaf/public_html/MIS_CSHRN/login.php on line 8

Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in /home/cshrnaf/public_html/MIS_CSHRN/login.php on line 9

Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in /home/cshrnaf/public_html/MIS_CSHRN/login.php on line 12

Query fails